# Remove hashtags from the end of a sentence

Tags: php, regex, hashtag

I would like to remove all words from the end of a text that are starting with a `space` and `#` sign.
URLS or hashtags within a sentence should not be remove.

Example text:

```
hello world #dontremoveme foobar http://example.com/#dontremoveme #remove #removeme #removeüäüö
```

I tried this but it removes all hashtags:

```
$tweet = "hello world #dontremoveme foobar http://example.com/#dontremoveme #remove #removeme #removeüäüö";
preg_match_all("/(#\w+)/", $tweet, $matches);
var_dump( $matches );
```

My idea is to check every word starting at the end of the text for a leading `#` with a `space` in front, until it's no longer the case.
How to translate that into a regular expression?

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like so: `( #[^# ]+?)+$` and replace it with an empty string.

An example is available [here](https://regex101.com/r/dG0mS8/2). Since you have non ASCII characters, the `.` operator (which matches any character) should help you tackle any character.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex matches all words starting with a `[Space]#` at the end of the line.

```
/( #\S+)*$/g
```

https://regex101.com/r/eH4bJ2/1

Comment: I tried it and got this error: `Warning: preg_match_all() [function.preg-match-all]: Unknown modifier 'g'` PHP: `$tweet = "hello world #dontremoveme foobar http://example.com/#dontremoveme #remove #removeme #removeüäüö";
preg_match_all("/( #\S+)*$/g", $tweet, $matches);
var_dump( $matches );` What do I need to change?

Comment: Try the following:

`$re = "/( #\\S+)*$/"; 
$str = "hello world #dontremoveme foobar http://example.com/#dontremoveme #remove #removeme #removeüäüö"; 
 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);`
 
This is the generated code which you can find here: https://regex101.com/r/eH4bJ2/1#code_0

Comment: That works but `print_r($matches)` outputs 2 arrays - how to get all tags in one array?

Comment: If you add a set of brackets arround the regex, the first match should be all hashtags togheter: `$re = "/(( #\\S+)*)$/"`, try it out... Otherwise, its a PHP problem, not a regex problem, you can solve it with standard PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This will do the job:

```
$tweet = "hello world #dontremoveme foobar http://example.com/#dontremoveme #remove #removeme #removeüäüö";
$res = preg_replace("/ #\p{L}+\b(?!\s+\p{L})/u", '', $tweet);
echo $res,"\n";
```

**Output:**

```
hello world #dontremoveme foobar http://example.com/#dontremoveme
```

Comment: I just tried your example and the "$res" echo is empty. Is there min. PHP version required or what do I miss? Thank you

Comment: @Tom: my php version is pretty old: `PHP 5.4.4-9 (cli) (built: Oct 26 2012 13:00:59)`. Did you do a copy/paste of the code? I've got exactly what I've written.

Comment: Yes, I used copy&paste and there is nothing else in the PHP file. My PHP version is: `PHP Version 5.3.28-nmm2` Any ideas?

Comment: @Tom: May be `5.3` doesn't handle unicode properties (`\p{L}`), try with `[a-züäö]` <- add any char concerned.

Comment: How can I check if the problem is my PHP Version `5.3.28-nmm2`?

Comment: @Tom: Sorry, I don't know. The only thing I can say is it's working with my version.